# Cannot build sox with FLAC support

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, flac, sox

I'm trying to configure and build `sox` v14.4.1 with FLAC support enabled, on Ubuntu.

I have downloaded and installed `flac` and done an `sudo ldconfig` (just in case the libs were wrongly linked), but somehow it's not showing on `sox`:

**Output of `./configure`**:

```
  lame......................no
```

How should this be fixed?`

Comment: Do you want to enable flac, or lame?

Comment: oops.  `flac`. not lame..